# acync await react/redux js async events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, async-await

https://ibb.co/dsNrnPQ   -- screenshot of error

I get a problem with an async event.
When logging into the site, when locale-storage is not ready yet. I can't get it async.
After refreshing the page, the problem goes away.

*Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0*

Problem in string

```
const userData = await userDataGetter();
```

```
export function setBalanseFetch(){

    return async dispatch => {

        const userData = await userDataGetter();


        const userID = await userData.userId;

        try{
            const respone = await axios.post('/api/profile', {userID})
            const json = await respone["data"];
            const FetchBalanse = json.items[0].balanse;
            dispatch( {type: FETCH_BALANSE, payload: Number(FetchBalanse)})
        }catch(e){
           
            console.log(`Axios spend balanse request failed: ${e}`);
        }
    }
}
```

code function userDataGetter

```
async function userDataGetter(){

    const userData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.userData);

    return userData;
}

export default userDataGetter
```

Comment: Could you please which data you get from your local storage because you didn't get the data from your local storage correctly, here  i meant => const userData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("keyName");

Comment: this way i get jwt token and user id. This code works, the problem occurs only at the first login after authorization, when data is added to the store at the same time and I want to get it. After refreshing the page, the problem goes away.

Comment: try to not make userDataGetter async , just like this                                                             function userDataGetter(){
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.userData);

    return userData;
}  and also when u try to access it , try this                                                           
     const userData = userDataGetter();

        const userID = userData.userId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

`const userData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.userData);`

However, `JSON.parse` is not an asynchronous function. It does *not* wait for a localStorage key to be present and ready, which is what your code seems to want it to do. (Also, as a comment pointed out, you want `localStorage.get('userData')`). Nor are you checking that it is present at all.

You also don't show where the localStorage is getting set. But likely your solution will be to *then* trigger the code that depends on it after you know its been set from the same place that's setting it, and when you need to access it any other time, check for its presence first.